# MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two questions about MongoDb and the c# driver, I am fairly new to the no-sql concept:

Consider the following class:

```
public class Company
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompanyEvent> CompanyEvents {get;set;}
}
```

1). How do I make sure the "Symbol" property is a unique constraint in collection? Do I have to write my own code to check before adding a new Company?

2). Lets say I add a company with 2 CompanyEvent classes in the collection, if I want to add a third event, would I have to grab the object first then add another CompanyEvent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use a unique index: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#unique-indexes

```
  var index = new IndexKeysBuilder<Company>();
  index.Ascending(c => c.Symbol);
  Collection.EnsureIndex(index, new IndexOptionsBuilder().SetUnique(true));
```

2) You have 2 options

- Read company object from database, add CompanyEvent, save company object to database
- Push CompanyEvent object to CompanyEvents Array in the database

  ```
  Collection.Update(
    Query<Company>.EQ(e => e.Id, id),
    Update<Company>.Push(e => e.CompanyEvents, new CompanyEvent()));
  ```

More information about push operator http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/

Comment: I thought that was only used for the id field. Learned something new.